# encoding video with HEVC codec in opencv (ffmpeg)

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, hevc

I have read documentation(https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu and https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) about opencv and ffmpeg, so I have compiled both parts. And when I call:

```
import cv2
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('test.mkv', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'HEVC'), 30, (1080, 1920))
```

or

```
import cv2
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('test.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'HEVC'), 30, (1080, 1920))
```

I'm getting following error `OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x43564548/'HEVC' is not found (format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)')'`. What is interesting, it works with h264 codec, previous version without compiling doesn't support h264. Do I have problem with ffmpeg or opencv?

I have docker image as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y  git cmake gcc g++ build-essential curl \
                        vim wget unzip yasm python3-dev \
                        python3-numpy libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev \
                        libswscale-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# compile ffmpeg
RUN apt-get install -y  autoconf automake build-essential cmake \
                        git-core libass-dev libfreetype6-dev \
                        libgnutls28-dev libsdl2-dev libtool \
                        libunistring-dev libva-dev libvdpau-dev \
                        libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev \
                        libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
                        pkg-config texinfo wget yasm \
                        zlib1g-dev libx264-dev libx265-dev libnuma-dev && \
    mkdir -p ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
    cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
    git -C x265_git pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git && \
    cd x265_git/build/linux && \
    cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" -DENABLE_SHARED=off ../../source && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
    wget -q -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xjf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
    cd ffmpeg && \
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
      --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
      --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
      --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
      --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
      --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
      --bindir="/usr/local/bin" \
      --enable-gpl \
      --enable-gnutls \
      --enable-libass \
      --enable-libfreetype \
      --enable-libvorbis \
      --enable-libx264 \
      --enable-libx265 \
      --enable-nonfree && \
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
    make install && \
    hash -r && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# compile opencv
RUN mkdir -p ~/opencv_sources && \
    git clone --depth 1 --branch 4.5.0 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git ~/opencv_sources && \
    mkdir -p ~/opencv_sources/build && cd ~/opencv_sources/build && \
    cmake -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON ../ &&
    make && make install
```

Comment: if "H264" works, try "H265". if "h264" works, try "h265". try "hvc1" too, analogous to "avc1".

Comment: looks like "hvc1" is working correctly with "mp4" extension. "We need to go deeper." :)